# Assign a name to every element of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to assign a name to every element of an array? For example in an array `myArr[5]`, can I give `myArr[0]` the name "First", `myArr[1]` "Second" and so on? And if not, what might be a feasible way to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, Whatever> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
yourMap.put("First", something);
yourMap.put("Second", somethingElse);
```

Then, to get elements out:

```
System.out.println(yourMap.get("First")); // prints something.toString()
System.out.println(yourMap.get("Second")); // prints somethingElse.toString()
// etc.
```

But if you're just going to use "First" and "Second" as keys, you're probably better off just using an array. Maps are useful when it's more convenient to access things using arbitrary objects rather than simple integers as keys.

Comment: If I have a two-dimensional array, how would I add the value of [j][k] to the corresponding hashmap?

Comment: I suppose you could have a `Map<String, Map<String, Whatever>>`, then get the values at ["Foo"]["Bar"] by using `yourMap.get("Foo").get("Bar")`.